# Centre elements in 3 columns within their respective widths. Align everything left when below 480px width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 things 1)phone number, 2)social icons and 3)email. First I want all three to be positioned centre in their respective widths.

Then while coming down to mobile screen size say below 480px all of them has to be left aligned and positioned below one after the other 1,2,3 (just like in responsive design).

I'm doing this for a responsive HTML email template. Help me with this!!

```html
<tr>
  <td class="cols-wrapper" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px"><br>
  <!--[if mso]>
    <table border="0" width="576" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 576px;">
    <tr><td width="192" style="width: 192px;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
    <table width="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row" style="width: 192px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;">
          <p>Phone: <a style="color:#00a5e7; border-bottom:none;" href="tel:+044 4000 2323">044 1234 5678</a></p>           
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <!--[if mso]></td><td width="192" style="width: 192px;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
    <table width="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row" style="width: 192px;">
      <tr>
      <td class="col" valign="top" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;padding-top:10px;">
       <a href="" target="_blank"><img style="float:left;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/3-20.png"></a>
      <a href=""><img style="padding:0px 8px; float:left;" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-twitter-20.png"></a>
      <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-chamfered-corner/154/google_plus-20.png"></a>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <!--[if mso]></td><td width="192" style="width: 192px;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
    <table width="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row" style="width: 192px;">
      <tr>
      <td class="col" valign="top" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px;">
        <p><a style="color:#00a5e7; border-bottom:none;" href="" target="_top">hi@website.com</a></p>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->

  </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple points I would like to mention.

1. First remove this table structure in your code -- which is useless, out of fashion, and increases unnecessary complexity.
2. Use **bootstrap** and add `col-md-4` in the 3 `divs` and put your 3 centered objects within it with `div { text-align: center }` and `col-xs-12` in all 3 of them with `div { text-align: left }`, like:

   ```
   <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12>item 1 </div> 
   <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12>item 2 </div> 
   <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12>item 3 </div>
   ```
3. Even if you don't want to use a framework like **bootstrap**, write the same code as I told in a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), like:

   ```
   @media only screen and (max-width:1024px){
      div{ 
          display:inline-block;
          width:33%;
          text-align:center;
      }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      div {
           display:block;
           text-align:left;
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm doing this for a responsive HTML email template. Okay, I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

try using a div for .cols-wrapper and remove the inline "float-styles" - add this CSS and you're ready to go. =)

```
<style media="screen">
    .cols-wrapper table{
        width: 33.33% !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        .cols-wrapper table{
            width: 100% !important;
            text-align: left;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: When I remove float the 3 social icons comes below one another. I need them to stay next to each other just like now.

Comment: This shouldn't happen - if you set the table's style to "text-align:center;", then the icons should appear next to each other, because they're wrapped in a link, which's an inline-element. Your links would look like this:

<a href=""><img style="padding:0px 8px; " src="https://ipsum.png"></a>

Comment: I'm not getting it. Can you use my code, correct it and modify your answer with the desired one.

Comment: Sorry for my late response - I wasn't on my computer this weekend.

You just have to remove the "float: left;" properties at your images and apply the styles I've posted. Usually I would recommend to structure your code a little bit simpler and not using inline-styles at all, but this should do the trick in this particular situation.

Comment: Forgot to mention: Maybe you must change your ".cols-wrapper" to a div to get this working properly:

`<div class="cols-wrapper" style="padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px">`